# How can I block ads from using my cel phone data plan?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network

I'd like a way to block ads from using my cell phone data plan. I've reviewed [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141885/ad-blocking-without-rooting-or-low-risk-rooting) but it didn't cover my specific question. The upshot is that I have roughly 1000 times the data available on my wifi connection as I have with my cell phone providers data plan. I get that developers need to keep the lights on and do so by serving us ads, however I resent having my high-speed data from my cell phone provider used up in this manner and would prefer to only receive ads over my wifi connection. How can I accomplish this? I've tried ADP (ad blocker plus) but it only proxies out wifi which is the exact opposite of what I have in mind. I have a Samsung SGH-T399 (aka Samsung Galaxy Light) running Android 4.2.2 The device is not rooted but I'd be willing to try that in order to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @beeshyams Done.

Comment: Not an elegant approach but on a rooted device, automation apps can easily disable or kill the app that is used to block ads when mobile data is active

Comment: @beeshyams Not quite what I have in mind.

Comment: True. That's why it's  not elegant, but that was the only approach I had since I haven't come across blocking ads criteria based on network connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off access to mobile data for all apps on the Samsung Galaxy 
Light by going to Settings->Connections->More Networks->Mobile networks and clearing the checkbox next to `Mobile data` This won't allow any data over the cell network, but data over wifi is still active. Note that this will likely have a negative impact on usability of a number of apps that require connectivity to operate as expected if you aren't connected via wifi, so you wmay want to flip it back on if your heading out.