# Does cell service provider has ability to display ads over other apps?

Tags: permissions, malware, mobile-network, ads, cell-broadcast

I came to realize that in rare occasions when using the Android phone, Cell service provider (Mobile Network provider) shows some popup advertisements. Regardless of the app, screen I was in it always mange to draw over the screen. Recently I manged to capture the screen when it does (Se attached image).

As I checked all the app's permissions to "Display over other apps" there were nothing other than some phone manufacture related and accessibility related system apps.

I find this as an security risk as cell provider can hijack my screen. Also I don't thing this is due to a malware/adware since all the ads are related to cell network and their packages.

- My question is how Android eco system enables this kind of facility?
- Which mechanism or the loopwhole Cell provider might be using?
- Is there anyway to disable this? (other than clicking over unsubscribe
  link on ad)

As you could see in the image, I was checking emails and ad got popped over
[image]

Edit:

- I do have a customer care/help app installed which provided by carrier. However I made sure it doesn't draw over apps.
- Device is non-rooted, and never touched the bootloader, so might be locked.
- Familiar with adb and fastboot. And adb lists the device with proper permission. However while running `adb shell appops query-op --user 0 SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow | while read line; do echo -e "\nPackage: $line "; appops get $line SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW; done` gives empty results.
- Tried `adb shell appops query-op --user 0 SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow` also but empty output

Comment: More likely to be from some network care /help app that is all the more likely, if your device is tied to the network.

Comment: Can you setup [tag:adb], than run this command: `adb shell appops query-op --user 0 SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow | while read line; do echo -e "\nPackage: $line "; appops get $line SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW; done`? Post the output in the question.

Comment: If your device is rooted (mention root status in question please), plenty of ad block solutions available, if not follow [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/141885/131553). Also try Adguard [ad blocker](https://adguard.com/en/welcome.html)

Comment: At the very least, a cell service provider (ISP) can intercept and inject ads on *non-HTTPS websites*. They can also send class 0 SMS. But to show ads over any apps is impossible without having an auxiliary Android app/service to do so.

Comment: FYI I did update the question with above commented suggestions.